# Search Google Docs for files shared by a specific person

Tags: google-drive

I'd like to use the Google Docs (or Google Drive) search box to find files shared with a co-worker. How can I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `from:` search operator to search documents shared from someone:

> from:name@example.com

Use the `to:` search operator to search documents shared to someone:

> to:name@example.com

You can also combine them. For example, the following will find your own documents shared with alice@example.com.

> from:me to:alice@example.com

Further information on searching can be found [here](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=50094).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it! One note for anyone else who has this issue: this search seems to be case sensitive.

Comment: Also note, doesn't seem to work with groups.

Answer (score -1):

all you have to do is know the individual's email, and make sure you only type that person's email